# Create OrderedDict from dict with values of list type (in the order of list's values)

Tags: python, algorithm

It is a bit hard for me to explain it in words, so I'll show an example:

What I have `(data` is a **dict** instance):

```
data = {'a':[4,5,3], 'b':[1,0,2], 'c':[6,7,8]}
```

What I need (`ordered_data` is an **OrderedDict** instance):

```
ordered_data = {'b':[0,1,2], 'a':[3,4,5], 'b':[6,7,8]}
```

The order of keys should be changed with respect to order of items in nested lists

Comment: should `ordered_data = {'b':[0,1,2], 'a':[3,4,5], 'b':[6,7,8]}` be `ordered_data = {'b':[0,1,2], 'a':[3,4,5], 'c':[6,7,8]}`

Answer (score 3):

```
tmp = {k:sorted(v) for k,v in data.items()}
ordered_data = OrderedDict((k,v) for k,v in sorted(tmp.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]))
```

First sort the values.  If you don't need the original `data`, it's OK to do this in place, but I made a temporary variable.

`key` is a function that returns a key to be sorted on.  In this case, the key is the second element of the item tuple (the list), and since lists are comparable, that's good enough.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, it will work in 2 or 3.  `sorted` takes iterables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OrderedDict` by sorting your items and the values :

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict(sorted([(k, sorted(v)) for k, v in data.items()], key=itemgetter(1)))
>>> d
OrderedDict([('b', [0, 1, 2]), ('a', [3, 4, 5]), ('c', [6, 7, 8])])
```

Answer (score -2):

Usually, you should not worry about the data order in the dictionary itself, and instead, jsut order it when you retrieve the dictionary's contents (i.e.: iterate over it):

```
data = {'a':[4,5,3], 'b':[1,0,2], 'c':[6,7,8]}
for datum in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]):
    ...
```